# How can I change the position of an imported model in Three.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, gltf

I'm trying to make a hologram with Three.JS (Pepperghost Effect) and for it to work I need 4 rotating models.

I have a working POC (https://gyazo.com/57da565593493a2c9971457632bb5552). This was an STL model, so I wasn't able to add textures to it. I did some research and gave gLTF's a shot. I got a model with textures and the importing all worked, but the rotation part was not working as I expected.

Here is a gif of the problem: https://gyazo.com/c5a1a8ee65f7da2cce1c83261d465b33
I want it to spin on its own axes instead of in circles. What I think is the problem, is that it doesn't import it centered, so it would be a problem with the model position and not the rotating part (which is `mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;` to be clear).

I tried moving the mesh with the `mesh.position.set()` function, but that moves the whole scene (I guess that's what you call it?).

Also, as you can see on the last gif, I have another problem where the chest is only displayed twice. Maybe this is tied to the other problem I have?

I tried putting it together in a `jsfiddle`, but since I cant upload the model that doesn't work. This is the 3D model I'm importing: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/chest-92a8d45d2d5c43b8b0b5bf7d97816ada

The peppersghost file can be found here https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/effects/PeppersGhostEffect.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Three.js Hologram POC</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.js"></script>
    <script src="peppersghost.js"></script>
    <!-- <script charset="utf-8" src="STLLoader.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="three.module.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <script type="module">



        var container;

        var camera, scene, renderer, effect, mesh, cube;
        var group;
        // var cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 0.25, 0 );

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );


            // console.log(window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight)
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 );



            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffd300 );

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);

            var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2.0, 200);
            camera.add(ambientLight);
            camera.add(light);

            scene.add(camera);

            camera.position.z = 1100;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);



            const gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            gltfLoader.load('/media/autoconvert/scene.gltf', (gltf) => {
                mesh = gltf.scene;
                // mesh.position.set(0, 100, 0)
                // mesh.scale.set(3, 1, 1);
                scene.add(mesh);


                const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);

                const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
                const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());


            });


            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            effect = new THREE.PeppersGhostEffect( renderer );
            effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            effect.cameraDistance = 5;

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

            // var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;
            // camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 3;
            // camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 3;
            // camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );


            effect.render( scene, camera );

        }

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for the help! I tried both solutions, but I am still encountering problems :(

First I tried getting the first child. Although it didnt spin in circles like it did before, it still rotates the wrong way and it only shows two models instead of four: https://gyazo.com/1da02beff790bbb440c42eec42540e56

Then I expanded and added a group like this: 
`group = new THREE.Group(); scene.add(group);` and `group.add(mesh)` instead of `scene.add(mesh)`.

This is what I got after that: https://gyazo.com/220f5eed04ec05c56000327b57837047

As you can see, it still isn't working. I am still trying to find a solution for my problem. Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: `gltf.scene` is an actual three.js [Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D) containing all the objects in the imported model, so the mesh you are looking for is a child of this scene. Most likely the first one, if there's nothing else in there. So try `mesh = gltf.scene.children[0]` and you should be able to control the position, scale, rotation of the model directly.

Comment: And to expand on this.. if you find the object does not rotate or scale around the pivot point that you want.. you can insert an Object3D or Group node as parent of you mesh, and then manipulate that instead of the mesh.. allowing you to use the meshes position/scale/rotation to set the pivot.

Comment: You can try to get center of bounding box\sphere. Something like that: const center = object.geometry.boundingSphere.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
    object.position.center(center);